# setTitleColor not working without setTitle

Tags: swift, settitle

I want to change the tint color of a button.

```
  button.setTitle("✸", for: .normal)
  button.setTitleColor(.green, for: .normal)
```

This is working fine with the code above. However when I remove the first line (setTitle), it does not work anymore.

I have set a title for the button in the interfacebuilder/storyboard. I can't figure out what is the reason for that.

---

More research. Just one of these options work when the title is set via the interface builder. But when I change the title of the Button, option2 does not longer work.

```
    // option 1
    button.setTitle("✸", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.green, for: .normal)
    
    // option 2
    button.tintColor = .red
```

Comment: is the button type ```custom```?

Comment: No, just a regular Button

Answer (score 0):

> I want to change the tint color of a button.

So why don't you set the tintColor?

```
button.tintColor = .red
```

...this works even if you set the title only in the interface builder.

Comment: tintColor is derived from the base class.
When you change the title with setTitle, tintColor does not longer work